# cpu you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu, 64-bit, wubi

I know there are already a few answers to this question but I can't seem to understand why I keep getting this error.

So here's the explanation:
I have 64 bits machine in which I've installed Windows 7 x64. I am compiling my Code under GCC (CodeBlocks) on Windows without any problem AT ALL. Then I decided that my application has to be portable, and I decided to compile it under GCC on Linux. In my other 32bit machine the code is compiling without any problem. However, on my 64 bit machine, I decided to install Ubuntu as Wubi. Of course I have installed Wubi x64 version as well.

I installed Ubuntu successfully under Wubi, I installed all necessary stuff, but when I try to compile my project, I get in the very first line the error 'cpu you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set'. Ok, this sounds completely non sense to me, taking into account that I've installed Wubi x64, on Windows 7 x64, on a 64bits machine. So why the hell am I getting an error saying that my CPU does not support x86-64 instruction set?

Could it be JUST because I have installed WUBI instead of installing Ubuntu on root in a normal way? I really can't seem to get this thing.

Thank you very much

**EDIT**: Ok, somewhere in Codeblocks I found the option that was checked for "Pentium M" architectures. I've unchecked it and now I get several erros such as:

error: cast from void* to int loses precision.

For which reason should this happen ONLY on Linux and not on Windows?

Comment: This answer hasn't helped? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11079910/777186

Comment: It may be useful to actually link to the other questions you mention, and perhaps explain which of the suggested approaches mentioned there you have tried.

Comment: This is not about your CPU, it's about _the CPU you are compiling your application for_.

Comment: That you get different errors/warnings on different compilers is not that surprising. One might be better at spotting a particular problem, or you use slightly different options on the systems.

Comment: What command is emitting that error message?

Comment: Also see ["CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set" error on Cygwin-x64](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35533259/608639). It tells you how to build OpenSSL 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 for Cygwin-x64.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on this comment:

> EDIT: Ok, somewhere in Codeblocks I found the option that was checked for "Pentium M" architectures. I've unchecked it and now I get several erros such as:

This was the reason for the compilation problem - "Pentium M" is a 32bit architecture. gcc under CodeBlocks will produce 32bit code on Windows *by default*

The error:

> error: cast from void* to int loses precision.

Is caused because the model for 64bit on linux x64 is `LP64`, where `sizeof(long) == sizeof(pointer) == 64bits`, and `sizeof(int) == 32bits` and you're trying to shove a pointer(`void *`)(64bits) into an `int`(32bits), which causes pointer information to be lost.

With a compilation error like that, it's most likely that the code is not 64bit clean.

> For which reason should this happen ONLY on Linux and not on Windows?

Linux on x64 defaults to producing 64bit applications, you would need to add `-m32` to the build options for the program to make it produce 32bit code (there is probably a CodeBlocks target option to do this)

Comment: Clear and Specific answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: anyway, does anyone know how to install the 32bit development kit for GCC on 64bit ubuntu?

Comment: From our friends over in unix.stackexchange.com - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12801/building-32-bit-on-a-64-bit-system

Comment: From the drop down menus, go to PROJECT->BUILD OPTIONS->COMPILER SETTINGS and under the GENERAL section, you should see options (near the bottom of that section) for -m32 and -m64.  It's a good idea to set it.  Never assume it's the default, especially when compiling for cross platform.

Note: if you do not see these options, you can add them yourself.  Just right click on GENERAL and select NEW FLAG.  You can add flags for both.  Code::Blocks v16.01 has them though, at least on the Windows build.