# Data type sizes in c

Tags: c

Wikipedia states that an (unsigned) int in c is at least 16 bits. I have come to the conclusion that on my windows pc it is in fact only 16 bits wide, but on my linux laptop it is 32 bits wide. That also means that the (unsigned) long is 32 and 64 bits wide respectively. Now my problem is that I need a 32 bit integer to store and pass around some information very quickly. That means that on linux I do

```
typedef unsigned int data
```

since this is 32 bits of data. On my windows pc however this typedef is too small since it only contains 16 bits. I could of course do

```
typedef unsigned long data
```

which would work on both platforms since it is at least 32 bits. The problem with this however is that it is much slower on my linux laptop since I'm asking for 32 extra bits that are completely unused. It is approximately 30% faster when using 32 bits instead of 64 and speed is essential in the program I'm writing.

Can I use the typedefs in a platform independent way to get 32 bits and 32 bits only? Is it otherwise possible to include directives like the following?

```
#if (int is 32 bits)
typedef unsigned int data
#else (long is 32 bits)
typedef unsigned long data
#endif
```

Comment: Use something like `uint32_t`, or perhaps `uint_fast32_t`.

Comment: [stdint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stdint.h)

Comment: If `int` is 16 bits on your platform and you're on Windows that almost certainly means that you're using TurboC. Am I right? BTW how did you find out that `int` is 16 bits on your platform?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't know what TurboC is but I'm using mingw.

Comment: @spinosarus123: I strongly doubt that any recent version of mingw has `sizeof(int) == 2`.

Comment: "It is approximately 30% faster when using 32 bits instead of 64 and speed is essential in the program I'm writing" -- That should generally not be the case when compiling 64-bit code and running it on a 64-bit CPU, unless the bottleneck of your program is memory bandwidth. My guess is that you configured the compiler to create 32-bit code. You should configure it to create 64-bit code.

Comment: @spinosarus123 OK; forget my comment regarding Turboc, but what makes you think `int` is 16 bits wide on your platform?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel How do I do that with gcc?

Comment: @spinosarus123: Are you using minGW-w64?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I meant on linux.

Comment: @spinosarus123: You can use the `-m64` command-line option on Linux in order to create a 64-bit executable. However, that is already the default, according to the information here: [How to compile a C++ program as 64-bit on 64-bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11078915/12149471) So as long as you are not explicitly using `-m32` (either directly or indirectly via makefile), I believe you are creating a 64-bit executable. If a 64-bit variable is indeed significantly slower than a 32-bit variable, then this is probably an issue of memory bandwidth, not CPU calculation speed.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I'm building a chess engine and when doing perft tests (counting amount of moves) the moves are the data stored as 32 bit integers. It's generating about 200 million moves (32 bit integers) per second. This is significantly slower when generating 200 million 64 bit integers.

Comment: Then this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking about the size of integers, which may or may not be the actual issue with your code, show your code as a [mre], explain what results you get and ask why that result is occuring. Suggest you post a new question along those lines.